# How to transfer binary files over http in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, http, binary, binaryfiles

I searched a lot, but not found something useful.
In my case I want to write a webserver in python3 and of course this **must** handle binary- and text files.

```
sockobj = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sockobj.bind(('localhost',8080))
sockobj.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sockobj.listen(1)
while True:
    conn, address = sockobj.accept()
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    head, data = getPic()
    conn.sendall(head + data) # Does not work at all
    conn.close()
```

I looked at wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol

Answer (score 2):

Lets say we have an image in png format called `image.png` and we want to transfer it over http to a client (e.g. Webbrowser).

```
import socket
def getPic():
    filebuffer = ""
    header = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-type: image/png\r\n\r\n"
    sfile = open("image.png", "rb")
    filebuffer = sfile.read()
    sfile.close()
    return header, filebuffer
def main():
    sockobj = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sockobj.bind(('localhost',8080))
    sockobj.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sockobj.listen(1)
    while True:
        conn, address = sockobj.accept()
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        head, data = getPic()
        if str(type(data)).find("str") > -1:
            conn.sendall(bytes(head + data, "ASCII"))
            #Since the most text files are in UTF-8 encoding, you can use the following instead:
            #conn.sendall(bytes(head, "ASCII") + bytes(data, "UTF-8")) 
        else:
            conn.sendall(bytes(head, "ASCII") + data)
        conn.close()
main()
```

---

#### Please note the following codes cut out from above code:

```
header = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-type: image/png\r\n\r\n"
sfile = open("image.png", "rb")
filebuffer = sfile.read()
sfile.close()
return header, filebuffer
```

```
head, data = getPic()
    if str(type(data)).find("str") > -1:
        conn.sendall(bytes(head + data, "ASCII"))
    else:
        conn.sendall(bytes(head, "ASCII") + data)
```

---

#### Why do you check, if the response body is in string or bytes?

Without that I get an error, if I open a text file with the code above. So I decided to encode all plain text to the ASCII character set.

#### Why are the http headers in ASCII coding?

Because it's specified in a W3C specification

#### Why takes the return statement two values

It cleans up the code when doing so and you can't combine strings with bytes together that would not work.

#### How to tell the client that I am going to send an image in png format?

The W3C has a solution for that called MIME types, these are a set of predefined and extensionable values for various file format. E.g. `image/png` says the browser that he gets a *image* file in *.png* format. For javascript it would be `application/javascript` and so on